# Why does Laravel api's are returning 405 error?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

So my scenario is:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function ($router) {

    Route::post('/login', [
        'as' => 'login',
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CustomerCrudController@login',
    ]);
    
    Route::post('/register', [
        'as' => 'register',
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CustomerCrudController@register',
    ]);
    
    Route::get('/logout', [
        'as' => 'logout',
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CustomerCrudController@logout',
    ]);
    
});
```

Here **Login API** is working perfectly using postman but register and logout api's are returning **405 method** not allowed error.
**Note:** I have already checked that I must be using post and get correctly. These API's were also working right previously. I don't know what has made them stop.

In case if someone wants to have a look at controller functions, here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Maha-Waqar/0a82da50c86b8c13a36090ef073f72b7). Looking forward to the suggestions.

Comment: Do they show up correct in `php artisan route:list`? "_I don't know what has made them stop._" What have you changed since then? (Curious, is Costumer a typo of Customer or do you sell costumes or something?)

Comment: Yes, they show up in route:list. [its typo]